# proxing express through nginx - reading the correct config file

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, nginx, configuration

I am trying to run my app on the server, but i have problems getting to run my enviorment.

I the follow tutorial:

```
http://antrikshy.com/blog/deploy-an-expressjs-app-on-digital-ocean-complete-succinct-guide/
```

I installed node and got my app runned it and it works at [IP]:3000

I installed nginx and it responds successful on [IP]

But the step with the configuration file is not clear to me my cond.d folder does not contain any .conf files... I am not sure my nginx uses the right config file. As a result, the my [IP]:3000 app is not reachable via [IP]

Any ideas regarding the problem are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various conventions for managing `nginx` configuration files which will be dependent on your specific OS.

As far as `nginx` is concerned, it will start with the `nginx.conf` file, probably somewhere like `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Within that file will be `include` directives to pull in other configuration text, which allows you to logically partition your servers.

There is probably a statement like:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

This means that you can create any file matching that pattern to add configuration text at that point within the master `nginx` configuration file. For example: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`